# Reload HBASE log4j properties without restart?

Tags: hadoop, log4j, hbase

i have changed HBASE log4j properties to log rotate. To reload the newly added properties i have to restart HBASE region server and HBASE Master.

Is there any way to reload HBASE log4j properties without restart.

Is there any HBASE command to reload log4j properties alone?

Comment: You need to restart the JVM that Hbase runs on

Comment: can we restart the JVM without restarting HMASTER and HREGIONSERVER?

Comment: Log4j doesn't care you're running Hbase. You must restart any service in order to reload the logger configuration